# Creating a surface correctly

Tags: matlab, surf

I want to create and show the surface z=x*exp(-x^2-y^2) in the section x,y~[-10;10]. I am trying to use:

```
x=-10:10;
y=-10:10;
z=x*exp(-x^2-y^2);
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(x,y,z);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

and getting:

"Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead."

I understand that `x` is a vector and so this is not a logical statement. Never the less, I do not have an Idea as to how to create this surface?

Comment: Writing "corectly" correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `meshgrid` *before* computing `z` so that you compute a value for `z` for each combination of `x` and `y`. Also you'll want to use element-wise operators (`.^` and `.*`) to create `z`

```
% Create all permutations of x and y
[x, y] = meshgrid(-10:10,-10:10);

% Compute z for each permutation
z = x .* exp(-x.^2 - y.^2);

% Plot as a surface
surf(x, y, z)
```